# Is "adios" an English word now?

Tags: loanwords, spanish

I recently heard an American being interviewed use the word "adios" casually in a sentence. The particular sense of the word seemed to be a sort of permanent "good bye."

Since the speaker was (as far as I know) a native English speaker this got me wondering if "adios" has become an loanword to English instead of being considered just a common Spanish word that many Americans happen to know.

When I was a kid I remember being taught "adios" in the context of Spanish; but this may also mean that over the decades it has become so commonly known & used to be considered now a part of English?

Comment: Probably the only way to know is to check reputable dictionaries

Comment: I would say, yes. It is in Merriam-Webster: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adios and in Collins: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/adios and presumably others

Comment: The English pronunciation, spelling, and use of *adios* are all different from the Spanish, so it's almost to if not at the point of *adieu*, beyond *ciao* or *sayonara*, and much further along than *auf widersehen*

Answer (score 3):

In essence you're asking whether or when "a common Spanish word that many `[English speakers]` happen to know" becomes an English loanword.

Loanwords are distinguished phonetically (they have sound combinations that are uncommon to English). They have a form similar to their origin language, but perhaps have modified spelling or (especially for English) optional diacritics. (Compare *resume* and the French word *résumé*.) *Adios* fits this pattern, coming from the Spanish *adiós* and being adapted to English vowel pronunciations. (Compare this video [presenting variations in American speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BSZ-f7mrc-Q) with [the Spanish version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=de6lFynaJZY). Now, imagine *adios* in a deep Southern American drawl. It happens.)

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/2386) cites instances of an Anglicized "Adios" or "A dios" as early as 1592:

> 1592   T. Lodge Euphues Shadow sig. L   With a friendly **Adios** he left him to his rest.

Its use within English syntax as a noun modified by an adjective in an ordinary way is significant. While its context remains *Spanish*, the word stands alone in English to denote a Spanish goodbye. It can also be used in English where other goodbye words would be expected, like this 20th century example:

> 1940   C. McCullers Heart is Lonely Hunter i. iv. 53   ‘**Adios**,’ Jake said. ‘I'll be back sometime soon.’

One could argue that Jake is code-switching between languages, but the general intelligibility of what he said among non-Spanish-speaking English speakers suggests that he's using a loanword. In closing, adios, aloha, and ciao!